# What are the supported wifi dongles for Ubuntu Precise?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I've been searching for a long time and just get led in confusing directions.

Where is a list of support WIFI USB dongles for Ubuntu 12.04 on the Beaglebone Black. I've ordered 2 already and can't get anything to work!

Comment: I would imagine any dongle with a native Linux driver (i. e., not Ndiswrapper) should work. Is this not the case?

Comment: I wonder if its more of an arm, or a power requirements issue

Answer (score 0):

I am using USB dongle Huawei E303C on Ubuntu 12.04. It has not shown any problem till now. Though it definitely has more options when I use it with Windows.
But when I was furious like you and looking for what to buy, I found many posts regarding problems with installing Huawei data card, So this does not mean that you should order third dongle. You should try installing drivers or some other configuration file. You might be ignoring something.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using said dongle on an ARM device like OP?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore: NO, Its Intel. I think you are right, it might be an ARM issue.